# How to make enemies turn and move towards player when near? Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make my enemy object turn and start moving towards my player object when the player comes within a certain vicinity.

For the turning I have been testing the transform.LookAt() function although it isn't returning the desired results as when the player is too close to the enemy object the enemy starts to tilt backwards and I only want my enemy to be able to rotate along the y axis, thanks in advance.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform visionPoint;
    private PlayerController player;

    public Transform Player;

    public float visionAngle = 30f;
    public float visionDistance = 10f;
    public float moveSpeed = 2f;
    public float chaseDistance = 3f;

    private Vector3? lastKnownPlayerPosition;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        player = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<PlayerController> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        // Not giving the desired results
        transform.LookAt(Player);
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {

    }

    void Look () {
        Vector3 deltaToPlayer = player.transform.position - visionPoint.position;
        Vector3 directionToPlayer = deltaToPlayer.normalized;

        float dot = Vector3.Dot (transform.forward, directionToPlayer);

        if (dot < 0) {
            return;
        }

        float distanceToPlayer = directionToPlayer.magnitude;

        if (distanceToPlayer > visionDistance)
        {
            return;
        }

        float angle = Vector3.Angle (transform.forward, directionToPlayer);

        if(angle > visionAngle)
        {
            return;
        }

        RaycastHit hit;
        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, directionToPlayer, out hit, visionDistance))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject == player.gameObject)
            {
                lastKnownPlayerPosition = player.transform.position;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at this https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/enemy-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the look at target:

```
void Update () {
    Vector3 lookAt = Player.position;
    lookAt.y = transform.position.y;
    transform.LookAt(lookAt);
}
```

this way the look at target will be on the same height as your object.

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class EnemyMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform Player;
    public float MoveSpeed = 4;
    int MaxDist = 10;
    int MinDist = 5;




    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(Player);

    if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) >= MinDist)
    {

        transform.position += transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;


        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Player.position) <= MaxDist)
        {
           // Put what do you want to happen here
        }

    }
}
```

}